# android sqlite database error in using where clause in comparing things

Tags: android, sqlite

i am getting this error please help-

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT SUM( amountinserted ) FROM
>   mbudgettablewheredatename='30-09-2017'

CODE:

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM( " +amountinserted + " ) " +
            "FROM " +tablename + "where" +datename + "='" + rmethod() + "'", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the code like the below code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM( " +amountinserted + " ) " + " FROM " +tablename + " **where** " +datename + "='" + rmethod() + "'", null);
```

You are missing white space before "**`FROM`**" and "**`where`**" in the query

Answer (score 0):

Use spaces around where clause as `+ " where "+`

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM( " +amountinserted + " ) " +
        " FROM " +tablename + " where " +datename + "='" + rmethod() + "'", null);
```

problem with spacing in query.Try this code